# XDocument: How to find an attribute value in nested xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Given the working code snippet below, I'm trying to get the `target` element inside `RootChild2`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eN4xV9

```
string str =
    @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>  
    <!-- comment at the root level -->  
    <Root>  
        <RootChild1>
            <Child>Content</Child>  
            <Child>Content</Child>  
            <Child>Content</Child>  
        </RootChild1>
        <RootChild2>
            <Child>Content</Child>  
            <Child key='target'>Content</Child>  
            <Child>Content</Child>  
        </RootChild2>
    </Root>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(str);

foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("RootChild2"))
{
    if (element.HasAttributes && element.Element("Child").Attribute("key").Value == "target")
        Console.WriteLine("found it");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

Comment: `element` here is `RootChild2`, which does *not* have attributes, so your `element.HasAttributes` is probably why it isn't working?

Comment: You could use the XPath expression:  `//Child[@key="target"]`

Comment: @Amy in this case, `//RootChild2/Child[@key="target"]` to avoid false positives against `RootChild1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This finds all 3 `RootChild2/Child` elements, then tests each in turn:

```cs
        foreach (XElement child in doc.Descendants("RootChild2").Elements("Child"))
        {
            if ((string)child.Attribute("key") == "target")
                Console.WriteLine("found it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("not found");
        }
```

Comment: @Rod well, if you're going to use xpath, you can do that from `doc` - you don't need `element.XPathSelect(...)` - just `doc.XPathSelect`

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems here:

- You're checking if the `RootChild2` element has any attributes - and it doesn't
- You're only checking the first `Child` element under each `RootChild2` element
- You're *assuming* the attribute is present (by dereferencing the `XAttribute`)

Here's code which will find *all* the target elements within a `RootChild2`:

```cs
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("RootChild2"))
{
    var targets = element
        .Elements("Child")
        .Where(child => (string) child.Attribute("key") == "target")
        .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine($"Found {targets.Count} targets");
    foreach (var target in targets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Target content: {target.Value}");
    }            
}
```

Note that the cast of `XAttribute` to `string` is a simple way of avoiding null reference issues - because the result of the explicit conversion is null when the source is null. (That's a general pattern in LINQ to XML.)

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the RootChild2-Element itself through `element` inside your loop.
Take a look at the following version:

```
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("RootChild2").Nodes())
        {
            if (element.HasAttributes && element.Attribute("key").Value == "target")
                Console.WriteLine("found it");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("not found");
        }
```

Now it loops through all nodes of RootChild2.

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your `foreach` loop at little bit, add accessing of child `Elements()` collection in `RootChild2` and check every element in enumeration. You also can check that `key` attribute is present in element to prevent a potential null reference exception

```cs
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("RootChild2").Elements())
{
    if (element.HasAttributes && element.Attribute("key")?.Value == "target")
        Console.WriteLine("found it");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("not found");
}
```

[`Descendants(XName)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Descendants_System_Xml_Linq_XName_) returns only elements with matching names, therefore you are getting only one `RootChild2` element as the result in your code